# Tensorflow looking for *101.dll but newest version of CUDA installs *102.dll

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a way to fix the above described issue? 
I am getting the following error when running my code:
[image]
and have narrowed the issue down to this
[image]
So the error is caused by a version missmatch, but this is the latest version of both CUDA and the tensorflow python library.
I am using the following version of tensorflow and python 3.8
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those DLLs are for CUDA version 10.2 while the latest Tensorflow supports CUDA 10.1.